# Unable to connect a dockerised keystone container with a dockerised mongo container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, keystone

I am trying to get a dockerised keystoneJS to talk to a dockerised mongoDB instance and I am struggling to see where I am going wrong in terms of linking them together. I have gone through the docker docs and similar examples online that are trying to do what I am trying to do, but still I am unable to get the two to talk to each other.

The main issues are it being unable to find 'localhost:27017' or Error: Invalid mongodb uri. Must begin with "mongodb://" Received: "mongodb://mongo:27017/"

Below are the relevant files:

```
Dockerfile for keystone

FROM node:6.9.1

RUN mkdir -p /docker
WORKDIR /docker

COPY . /docker
RUN npm install --no-optional

CMD ["node", "keystone.js"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
keystone:
image: keystone-test
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
depends_on:
  - mongo
networks:
  - localnetwork
environment:
  - MONGO_URI="mongodb://mongo:27017/"

mongo:
image: mongo:3
command: mongod --smallfiles
ports:
  - "27017:27017"
networks:
  - localnetwork

networks:
  localnetwork:
```

keystone.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
..... and some usual keystone stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

It takes me a lot of time to figure out. In your `docker-compose.yml`, the **MONGO_URI** shouldn't wrap in double quotes, it should be **`mongodb://mongo:27017/`** instead of **`"mongodb://mongo:27017"`**. **MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/** instead of **MONGO_URI="mongodb://mongo:27017/"**